# How to run external query through local resolver in Apollo Client

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-boost

I have one more question. On my server I have something like:

```
extend type Query {
  login (input: LoginInput!): Response
}
```

On the client, I am trying to make the query:

```
query Login ($input: LoginInput!) {
  login (input: $input) {
    login @client
  }
}
```

I have a resolver:

```
const login = parent => {
  console.log (`parent`, parent)
}
```

and:

```
  resolvers: {Response: {login}}
```

So far so good.

The problem is - the resolver logs

```
{
  __typename: "Response"
}
```

I don't actually get the object (the Response). If I copy the function to the server, I get it. This behavior is the same for `useQuery`, `useMutation`, `useLazyQuery`. Furthermore, if I change `login @client` to `success message`, then I get both, so there's doesn't seem to be a typo.

Is there some gotcha that one has to keep in mind (I am not using async anywhere, assuming Apollo takes care of that), or should I submit an issue, because it looks like a bug?

Cheers!

Comment: Just found the answer!

Comment: You can answer your own question and later accept it. This helps other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is pretty trivial - I'm not querying any fields!

Replace

```
login @client
```

by

```
success
message
login @client
```